# Java tcp server programming does not work

Tags: java, sockets

I use this code to run simple TCP Server by JAVA and I use Socket Protocol android application to be client.  The problem is when the client connected then I send the message the Server side do nothing until I disconnected the client the massage appear after that. I think something stuck at 
        while((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null)

```
import java.net.*;
import java.io.*;

public class TCPIP {

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    ServerSocket serverSocket = null;
    try{
        serverSocket = new ServerSocket(10007);
    }
    catch(IOException e)
    {
        System.err.println("Could not listen on port 10007");
        //System.exit(1);
    }
    Socket clientSocket = null;
    System.out.println("Waiting for connection....");

    try{
        clientSocket = serverSocket.accept();
    }
    catch(IOException e){
        System.err.println("Accept Failed");
        //System.exit(1);
    }
    System.out.println("Connection Successful");
    System.out.println("Waiting for input");

    PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(clientSocket.getOutputStream(),true); 
    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(clientSocket.getInputStream()));


    String inputLine;


    while((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) 
    {
        System.out.println("Server: "+ inputLine);
        out.println(inputLine);

        if(inputLine.equals("Bye."))
        {
            break;
        }
    }
    out.close(); 
    in.close(); 
    clientSocket.close(); 
    serverSocket.close(); 
}

}
```

Comment: Is your client actually sending a line?

Comment: Yes it is. Because I test this android app(my client) with c# socket before.

Comment: It needs to be more specific: a line ends with a newline. Probably the client is not sending a newline and so the readLine() method is still waiting for it.

Comment: I just forget to send newline! Thank you guys

Answer (score 1):

```
while((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null)
```

is bad code, you should use

```
inputLine = in.readLine();
while(inputLine != null)
{
   inputLine = in.readLine();
}
```

instead. `readLine()` waits for the newline-character - make sure your server sends it or else your client will block until the connection is closed : https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/BufferedReader.html#readLine()

> Reads a line of text. **A line is considered to be terminated by any one
>   of a line feed ('\n'), a carriage return ('\r'), or a carriage return
>   followed immediately by a linefeed**.